# Переменная не перезаписывается внутри вызова метода wall.get

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Доброго времени суток. 
Нужно написать функцию с входящим параметром `id`, которая бы возвращала кол-во всех записей на стене юзера. 
Написал вот так:

```
function getPostsAmountById(id) {
    var p_count = 0;
    VK.Api.call('wall.get', {
        owner_id: id,
        v: 5.57
    }, function (r) {
        if (r.response) {
            p_count = r.response.count;
            console.log(p_count); //выведет 224(реальное кол-во записей
        }
    });
    return p_count;
}
console.log(getPostsAmountById(1)); //выведет 0
```

Можно было бы ограничиться выводом в самом вызове метода, но мне нужно, чтобы метод перезаписывал переменную, дабы в дальнейшем я мог манипулировать её значением.
Один очень хороший человек(огромное спасибо Support Agent #368) кое-что мне объяснил:

> API.call вызывается асинхронно, поэтому с переменной он так себя и ведет (он о ее существовании снаружи еще не знает, когда вызывается).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне решить данную проблему.

**UPD #1**
Немного почитав про Promise(спасибо за подсказку Yuri), решил попробовать отредактировать функцию. Вроде бы работает. Возвращает то, что мне нужно.
Но правильно ли я написал? Будут какие-то замечания/подсказки?

```
function getPostsAmountById(id) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        VK.Api.call('wall.get', {
            owner_id: id,
            v: 5.57
        }, function (r) {
            if (r.response) {
                resolve(r.response.count);
            }
        });
    });
}
getPostsAmountById(1).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Всё верно вам сказали. В момент, когда функция возвращает p_count, колбэк для API.call ещё не отработал. Если вам нужно получить это значение, используйте, например, Promise.